# How to solve old GLIB error

Tags: gtk, environment-variables, glib

I am in the process of installing GTK+ but it needs various pre-requisites.  These are

- glib - 2.0 >= 2.35.3
- atk  -     >= 2.7.5
- Pango-     >= 1.32.4
- gdk-pixbuf-2.0 >= 2.27.1

Now I upgraded my glib-2.0 to 2.38.2, and I've tried upgrading atk, pango and gdk-pixbuf

```
checking for GLIB - version >= 2.31.2... 
'pkg-config --modversion glib-2.0' returned 2.38.2, but GLIB (2.32.4)
was found! If pkg-config was correct, then it is best
to remove the old version of GLib. You may also be able to fix the error
by modifying your LD_LIBRARY_PATH enviroment variable, or by editing
/etc/ld.so.conf. Make sure you have run ldconfig if that is
required on your system.
If pkg-config was wrong, set the environment variable PKG_CONFIG_PATH
to point to the correct configuration files

configure: error: 
GLIB 2.31.2 or better is required. The latest version of
GLIB is always available from ftp://ftp.gtk.org/. If GLIB is installed
but not in the same location as pkg-config add the location of the file
glib-2.0.pc to the environment variable PKG_CONFIG_PATH.
```

I have been go round in circles for the past few hours trying to get this working, if anyone out there can help it would be much appreciated.  Thanks in advance

Comment: How did you upgrade glib?

Comment: Downloaded it from http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/sources/glib/ and  just did the ./configure && make && make install

Comment: The package manager doesn't know you installed the newer glib and only sees the older version. What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: 12.04 is my version of Ubuntu chaskes

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem as you.

I set `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` as

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
```

see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11228173/how-to-find-where-older-version-of-glib-has-been-installed

But it didn't work. Then I found someone solve it as

```
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib
```

see http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/how-to-set-ld_library_path-pkg_config_path-and-glib_config-937732/

And it did work!

Answer (score 0):

I tested this so many times, and i verified that if we installed glib from source, we have to options:

1. If with do `./configure --prefix=/usr --with-pcre=system` , like in [instructions](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/cvs/general/glib2.html), it means that we have glib installed in `/usr/lib path`. So, we need to make `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib`.
2. If we don't use `--prefix=`the default path is `/usr/local/lib/`. So, if `pkg_config`finds two libraries installed we need to make `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib`if we installed in default path.

Hope it helps someone.