# How can i downgrade a package installed from source?

Tags: downgrade, source, glib

i installed glib2.42 from source but that's creating a problem for me. So i tried to downgrade it running `make uninstall` and installed glib2.28 afterwards. But now when i try to build a software using glib a dependency, it shows this error:

```
*** 'pkg-config --modversion glib-2.0' returned 2.28.8, but GLIB (2.42.1)
*** was found! If pkg-config was correct, then it is best
*** to remove the old version of GLib. You may also be able to fix the error
*** by modifying your LD_LIBRARY_PATH enviroment variable, or by editing
*** /etc/ld.so.conf. Make sure you have run ldconfig if that is
*** required on your system.
*** If pkg-config was wrong, set the environment variable PKG_CONFIG_PATH
*** to point to the correct configuration files
no
configure: error: Cannot find GLIB: Is pkg-config in your path?
```

How can i resolve this and keep gib2.28?

Answer (score 0):

Try what the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/423896/how-to-solve-old-glib-error) suggests, use these commands:

```
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib
```

Comment: Sorry. It didn't help. I guess its creating a problem downgrading. If only i knew how to do that properly.

Comment: `sudo apt-get purge glib` then `sudo apt install glib` to get the distribution's version if you want that. That's assuming removing glib entirely won't completely break your system...

Comment: Will apt-get purge glib remove all the traces of glib built from source also?