# How to solve old GLIB error while installing "pygobject" using jhbuild

Tags: python, pygtk, glib, pygi, jhbuild

I am trying to install `pygobject` using `jhbuild`. And I am getting this error:

```
configure: error: Package requirements (glib-2.0 >= 2.48.0) were not met:
Requested 'glib-2.0 >= 2.48.0' but version of GLib is 2.38.2
```

So, I have installed `glib-2.0` from https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/%2Bsource/glib2.0 using

```
./configure
make
make install
```

After installing this library I have tried again and getting same error.

So I check this [How to solve old GLIB error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/423896/how-to-solve-old-glib-error) question. And tried setting two variables like this

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib
```

And than tried again but no luck :(

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: Why did you [re]installed glib-2.0? You had already version `2.38.2` according to your error message. So I would update your libraries: `sudo apt-get update` that is the safest way. If the version is still `<2.48.0` then go for manual installation, but this can be tricky, as you see :-\. Now, for Ubunut 16.04. the current `libglib2.0-0` is version `2.48.2`, maybe a reason for migrating into the higher version.

Comment: Another hint: sometimes when installing python packages, it helps to install also the `dev` package of the library (see link[post here](https://github.com/molefrog/cupsidity/issues/2)), so that python installs and works properly. Try, thus, installing also `libglib2.0-dev`, it might work.